# Knockout.js: How to sort table?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, knockout.js

I use this example:

http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/real-time-system-resource-monitor-with-signalr-mvc-knockout-and-webapi/#comment-3293

Table displays observable array. This array is updating by clients via signalr. All works fine.
I want to add sorting by selected column.

```
<div id="computerInfo">

<h2>Real-time System Resource Monitor</h2>
<h5 data-bind="visible: connected">Connected to message hub</h5>

<table border="0" class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Machine</th>
        <th>CPU %</th>
        <th>Memory Available (Mb)</th>
        <th>Total Memory (Mb)</th>
        <th>Mem Available %</th>
    </tr>

    <!-- ko foreach: machines -->
    <tr data-bind="css: { highCpu: cpu() > 90 || memPercent()<30 }">
        <td data-bind="text: machineName"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: cpu"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: memUsage"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: memTotal"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: memPercent"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- /ko -->

</table>
```

```
$(function () {

    // The view model that is bound to our view
    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        // Whether we're connected or not
        self.connected = ko.observable(false);

        // Collection of machines that are connected
        self.machines = ko.observableArray();

        self.headers = [
                            { title: 'Machine Name', sortKey: 'keyMachineName' },
                            { title: 'CPU', sortKey: 'keyCpu' },
                            { title: 'Mem Usage', sortKey: 'keyMemUsage' },
                            { title: 'Mem Total', sortKey: 'keyMemTotal' },
                            { title: 'Mem Percent', sortKey: 'keyMemPercent' }
        ];
        self.sort = function (header, event) {
            var sortKey = header.sortKey;
            //implementation of sort
        };
        self.sort = function (header, event) {
            var sortKey = header.sortKey;
            switch (sortKey) {
                case 'keyMachineName':
                    self.machines.sort(function (a, b) {
                        var n = a.machineName < b.machineName ? -1 : a.machineName > b.machineName ? 1 : 0;
                        alert(n);
                        return n;//1;
                    });
                    break;
                case 'keyCpu':
                    self.machines.sort(function (a, b) {
                        var n = a.cpu < b.cpu ? -1 : a.cpu > b.cpu ? 1 : 0;
                        alert(n);
                        return n;
                    });
                    break;
                case 'keyMemUsage':
                    self.machines.sort(function (a, b) {
                        var n = a.memUsage < b.memUsage ? -1 : a.memUsage > b.memUsage ? 1 : 0;
                        alert(n);
                        return n;
                    });
                    break;
            }
        };
    };

    // Instantiate the viewmodel..
    var vm = new ViewModel();

    // .. and bind it to the view
    //ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#computerInfo")[0]);

    // Get a reference to our hub
    var hub = $.connection.cpuInfo;

    // Add a handler to receive updates from the server
    hub.client.cpuInfoMessage = function (machineName, cpu, memUsage, memTotal) {

        var machine = {
            machineName: machineName,
            cpu: cpu.toFixed(0),
            memUsage: (memUsage / 1024).toFixed(2),
            memTotal: (memTotal / 1024).toFixed(2),
            memPercent: ((memUsage / memTotal) * 100).toFixed(1) + "%"
        };

        var machineModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(machine);

        // Check if we already have it:
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.machines(), function (item) {
            return item.machineName() == machineName;
        });

        if (!match) {
            vm.machines.push(machineModel);
        } else {
            var index = vm.machines.indexOf(match);
            vm.machines.replace(vm.machines()[index], machineModel);
        }

       // vm.machines.sort();


        //ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#computerInfo")[0]);

        //$("#infoTable").tablesorter({sortList: [0,0]});
    };

    ///


    ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#computerInfo")[0]);
    ///
    // Start the connectio
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        vm.connected(true);
    });
});
```

The problem is:
sort function always returns 0, i.e. there values always the same:

**var n = a.machineName < b.machineName**

When I for the test return 1 then sorting works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a machine using

```
var machineModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(machine);
```

you create a view model with observable properties. In this case in your sort method you need to treat them as observables, so you must use them using parenthesis. For example:

```
case 'keyMachineName':
    self.machines.sort(function (a, b) {
        var n = a.machineName() < b.machineName() ? -1 : a.machineName() > b.machineName() ? 1 : 0;
        alert(n);
        return n;//1;
    });
break;
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery tablesorter plugin does not work with knockout. Simply forget it.

Knockout cannot handle when DOM nodes are moved around without its knowledge, but that's what jQuery Tablesorter does.

But knockout is perfectly prepared to sort your table for you.

Below example features

- fully configurable columns, i.e. not hard-coded in the view
- sortable table columns on click, including visual feedback which is the sorted column
- alternating ascending/descending sort order
- value formatting via a [Knockout extender](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html)
- automatic update of values in an interval (likely scenario in this use case)
- automatic re-sort when the values update

```js
ko.extenders.formatted = function (underlyingObservable, formatFunction) {
    underlyingObservable.formatted = ko.computed(function () {
        return formatFunction(underlyingObservable());
    });
};

function Machine(data) {
    var self = this,
        memoryFormat = function (val) { return Math.round(val / 1024, 0).toLocaleString(); };
        
    self.machineName = ko.observable().extend({formatted: function (val) { return val; }});
    self.cpu = ko.observable(0).extend({formatted: function (val) { return val.toFixed(1); }});
    self.memUsage = ko.observable(0).extend({formatted: memoryFormat});
    self.memTotal = ko.observable(0).extend({formatted: memoryFormat});
    self.memPercent = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.memUsage() / self.memTotal() * 100;
    }).extend({formatted: function (val) { return val.toFixed(1) + '%'; }});
    self.conditions = ko.computed(function () {
        return {
            highCpu: self.cpu() > 50,
            lowMem: self.memPercent() < 30
        };
    });
    
    self.update(data);
};
Machine.prototype.update = function (data) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
};

function MachineList() {
    var self = this;

    self.connected = ko.observable(false);
    self.machines = ko.observableArray();
    self.headers = [
        {title: 'Machine Name', key: 'machineName', cssClass: ''},
        {title: 'CPU %', key: 'cpu', cssClass: 'right'},
        {title: 'Mem Usage (MB)', key: 'memUsage', cssClass: 'right'},
        {title: 'Mem Total (MB)', key: 'memTotal', cssClass: 'right'},
        {title: 'Mem Available %', key: 'memPercent', cssClass: 'right'}
    ];
    self.sortHeader = ko.observable(self.headers[0]);
    self.sortDirection = ko.observable(1);
    self.toggleSort = function (header) {
        if (header === self.sortHeader()) {
            self.sortDirection(self.sortDirection() * -1);
        } else {
            self.sortHeader(header);
            self.sortDirection(1);
        }
    };

    // use a computed to subscribe to both self.sortHeader() and self.sortDirection()
    self.sortMachines = ko.computed(function () {
        var sortHeader = self.sortHeader(),
            dir = self.sortDirection(),
            tempMachines = self.machines(),
            prop = sortHeader ? sortHeader.key : "";
        if (!prop) return;
        tempMachines.sort(function (a, b) {
            var va = ko.unwrap(a[prop]),
                vb = ko.unwrap(b[prop]);                
            return va < vb ? -dir : va > vb ? dir : 0;
        });
        self.machines.notifySubscribers();
    });
    self.insertMachine = function (data) {
        var machine = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.machines(), function (item) {
            return ko.unwrap(item.machineName) == ko.unwrap(data.machineName);
        });

        if (machine) machine.update(data);
        else vm.machines.push(new Machine(data));
        self.sortMachines();
    };
};

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// connection mockup
$.connection = {
    cpuInfo: {client: {}},
    hub: {start: function() { return $.Deferred().resolve(); }}
};

var vm = new MachineList(),
    hub = $.connection.cpuInfo;

hub.client.cpuInfoMessage = function (data) { vm.insertMachine(data); };

// start the connection as soon as possible...
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    vm.connected(true);
    $(function () {
        // ...but don't apply bindings before the document is ready
        ko.applyBindings(vm, $("#computerInfo")[0]);
    });

    // create some random sample data
    setInterval(function () {
        var GB = 1024 * 1024;
        ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].forEach(function (name) {
            hub.client.cpuInfoMessage({
                machineName: name,
                cpu: getRandomInt(0, 1000) / 10,
                memUsage: getRandomInt(5 * GB, 7 * GB),
                memTotal: 10 * GB
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
});

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

```css
.table { border-collapse: collapse; }
.table th, .table td { border: 1px solid silver; padding: 0 2px; }
.sortable { cursor: pointer; }
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #f7f7f7; }
.highCpu { color: red; }
.lowMem { color: red; }
.right { text-align: right; }
.sorted { background-color: #B5E0FF; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<div id="computerInfo">
  <h2>Real-time System Resource Monitor</h2>
  <h5 data-bind="visible: connected">Connected to message hub</h5>

  <table border="0" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr data-bind="foreach: headers">
        <th class="sortable" data-bind="click: $root.toggleSort, text: title, css: {sorted: $data === $root.sortHeader()}"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: machines">
      <tr data-bind="foreach: $root.headers, css: conditions">
        <td data-bind="text: $parent[key].formatted, css: cssClass"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```